# Recursion function is not responding

Tags: c++, recursion

```
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class mm
{    
private:
    int k[1000];
    int n;
    int i;
    int a;
    int b;
    int f;

public:
    mm ()
    {
        a=0;
        b=1;
        f=0;
        i=0;
        for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
            k[i]=0;
    };

   ~mm()
   {
   }

    void fib(int n)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if (i<=1)
                f=i;
            else
            {
                f=a+b;
                a=b;
                b=f;
            }
              k[i]=f;
        }

        for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
            cout<<k[j]<<" ";
    }

    int se (int n, int i)
    {
        if (n==1)
        return 1;
        else
        return 1/k[i] + se (n-1, i+1);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter n:";
    cin>>n;
    mm p;
    cout<<"fib: "<<endl;
    p.fib(n);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"se: ";
    cout<<p.se(n,0);
    return 0;
}
```

Recursion function from main is not responding. Maybe the array `k[i]` is not working, but I cant find the reason. Can anyone help me?

Comment: mmmm. what do u mean exactly with "not responding"???. And what it means that an array is "not working" too?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: You didn't set a default value for n in the constructor for mm

Comment: i have stored all the Fibonacci value in an array k[1000], and then i tried to use the array in this "return 1/k[i] + se (n-1, i+1);" for the series of 1+ 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + .......

Comment: Additionally, you should just use a `vector` to store those 0's anyway. What if the user gives a number higher than 1000?

Comment: Initially i am good with 1000.

Answer (score 0):

k[0] is set to 0. When you then call  se(n,0) in main, it computes 1/k[0] + se(n-1,1) which is a division by zero.